# ¿Cómo registrar datos almacenados en un array enviados desde html con php, bd mysql aplicando patron mvc?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, poo

BUEN DÍA AMIGOS ESTOY APRENDIENDO PHP APLICANDO MVC Y POO EL PROBLEMA QUE TENGO ES DE REGISTRAR EN MYSQL DATOS ALMACENADOS EN UN ARRAY NECESITO DE SU AYUDA YA E INTENTADO DE VARIAS MANERAS.

ESTRUCTURA DEL PROYECTO

[image: ESTRUCTURA DEL PROYECTO]

MI CLASE Model.php HACE LA CONEXION A LA BD:

```
<?php 

abstract class Model{
private $servidor = 'localhost';
private $usuario = 'root';
private $contraseña = '';
private $bd = 'personas';
private $bd_caracteres = 'utf8';
protected $query;
private $conex;
protected $rows = array();

abstract protected function create($estado=array());
abstract protected function read();
abstract protected function update($idEstado,$estado);
abstract protected function delete($estado);

private function abrirConexion(){
    $this->conex=new mysqli($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->contraseña,$this->bd);

    $this->conex->set_charset($this->bd_caracteres);
}

private function cerrarConexion(){
    $this->conex->close();
}

protected function setQuery(){
    $this->abrirConexion();
    $this->conex->query($this->query);
    $this->cerrarConexion();
}

protected function getQuery(){
    $this->abrirConexion();
    $resultado=$this->conex->query($this->query);
    while( $this->rows[] = $resultado->fetch_assoc() );
    $resultado->close();
    $this->cerrarConexion();

    return array_pop($this->rows);
}
}

?>
```

AL EJECUTAR EL PROYECTO CARGA PRIMERO EL VistaUsuario.php

VistaUsuario.php

```
<?php
require('../Controller/ControllerUsuario.php');

$controllerUsuario = new ControllerUsuario();
$datos = $controllerUsuario->read('');

?>

<div>
<section>
    <form method="POST" action="../Controller/ControllerUsuario.php">
        <input type="hidden" action="action" name="registrar">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Usuario:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtUsuario"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Nombre:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtNombre"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fecha Nacimiento:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtFechaNacimiento"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Contraseña:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="txtContraseña"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Tipo de Usuario:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="rdbTipoUsuario" value="Administrador" id="admin"><label for="admin">Administrador</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rdbTipoUsuario" value="Usuario" id="user"><label for="user">Usuario</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnRegistrar" value="Registrar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</section>
```

LOS DATOS DE LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO LAS MANDO POR POST AL CONTROLADOR ControllerUsuario.php

ControllerUsuario.php

```
<?php
require('../Model/ModelUsuarios.php');

class ControllerUsuario{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new ModelUsuarios();
    }

    public function create($usuario=array()){
        return $this->model->create($usuario);
    }

    public function read($usuarios){
        return $this->model->read($usuarios);
    }

    public function update(){

    }

    public function delete(){

    }
}

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    $controller = new ControllerUsuario();
    if($_POST['action'] == 'registrar'){
        $usuario = array(
            'usuario' => $_POST['txtUsuario'],
            'email' => $_POST['txtEmail'],
            'nombre'=> $_POST['txtNombre'],
            'nacimiento' => $_POST['txtFechaNacimiento'],
            'contraseña' => $_POST['txtContraseña'],
            'tipoUsuario' => $_POST['rdbTipoUsuario']
        );
        $controller->create($usuario);
    }
}
 ?>
```

AHORA DEL CONTROLADOR PASA AL MODELO ModelUsuarios.php

ModelUsuarios.php

```
<?php 
require('Model.php');

class ModelUsuarios extends Model{
public function create($usuario=array()){
    for ($i=0; $i < count($usuario); $i++) { 
        $sql = "insert into 
usuarios(usuario,email,nombre,fechaNacimiento,contraseña,tipoUsuario) 
        values('$usuario[$i]['usuario']','$usuario[$i] 
 ['email']','$usuario[$i]['nombre']','$usuario[$i]['nacimiento']',
                $usuario[$i]['contraseña'],$usuario[$i]['tipoUsuario']')";
    }

    $this->query=$sql;
    $this->setQuery();
}

public function read($usuario=''){
    if($usuario == ''){
        $sql = "select * from usuarios";
    }else{
        $sql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='$usuario'";
    }

    $this->query=$sql;
    $this->getQuery();

    $datos = array();

    foreach ($this->rows as $key => $value) {
        array_push($datos,$value);
    }

    return $datos;
}

public function update($idUsuario,$usuario){

}

public function delete($usuario){

}
} 
 ?>
```

LUEGO LA SENTENCIA SQL SE ALMACENA EN LA VARIABLE $sql QUE PASA POR MEDIO DE LA VARIABLE $query al MODELO PARA SER EJECUTADO CON LA FUNCION setQuery() PERO NO REGISTRA NADA. ESPERO HABER SIDO BIEN ESPECIFICO GRACIAS.

Comment: Por favor, evita el uso de TODO MAYÚSCULA, es de mal gusto en el mundo de la programación. Luego, no hace falta que nos pongas todo tu programa. Dinos cuál es la parte que no funciona y si necesitamos algo te lo pediremos... Tal y como está todo planteado ahora, habría que hacer un máster en tu aplicación para entenderla primero y luego para detectar el problema. No facilitas una solución soltando todo el código en la pregunta como estás haciendo.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder tomare en cuanto tu consejo como mencione mas arriba recién estoy aprendiendo es por eso que puse todo el código para que me puedan entender.

Comment: Entiendo, pero comprende que no es fácil meterse a analizar toda la lógica de tu programa. Es mejor que nos digas: *intento hacer esto y tengo este problema en esta parte del código y me arroja este mensaje de error*. Si falta algo te diremos: *falta esto, edita la pregunta y pon cómo estás haciendo tal cosa*. Y tú editas la pregunta poniendo eso y así nos ayudamos mejor. Podrías empezar depurando las variables, con `var_dump($variable);` para verificar que están llegando bien. Revisando la conexión, etc.

Comment: Por fin encontré el problema me había equivocado en esta parte en el action="action" name="registrar" . 

La solución sería de esta manera.
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="registrar">